# Wifi Router That Allows me to assign devices a frequency

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wireless-router

**Current Setup**
**Wifi**: 1 Google Wifi router running version 12371.52.22

**Living**: Big city high rise with crowded 2.4 spectrum.  Our apartment is ~840 sqft.

**Troubleshooting**: 97% of our devices work fine & are not impacted by the collisions on the 2.4 frequency. But, I wish Google Wifi was better at the automatic channel changing. As I write this, an analyzer shows 20+ networks, with ~5 of them are on my same 2.4 channel. Google Wifi currently doesn't support manual channel changing, but I digress. Because this frequency is very commonly crowded, 2 of our work devices do not work on that frequency, we believe due to the speed combined with our work VPNs. Currently we are stuck disconnecting & reconnecting wifi until it switches back to the 5 ghz frequency, where we never have any issues.

**Possible Solutions:** We are looking at a different routers, but want one that still combines the two frequencies (2.4 & 5) into one SSID. There is a lot of benefit for this as we have a few legacy devices that require 2.4 & dont want to have to keep switching back and forth networks to use certain devices. But since 2.4 seems to be the issue for our work laptops, we are looking for a system that we can assign a device to ALWAYS connect using a certain frequency. We have looked at "client side" solutions; but both work laptops are pretty locked down, which makes configuration changes nearly impossible. Our last option would be to run a cat5 cable, but this isn't ideal for a few reasons...

**Given the context does anyone have any suggestions on how we can solve for our issue(s)?**

Is there a router out there that does what we are in need of?

Is there a better setup that would be achieves our goal?

...

Thank you!

Comment: Note that different SSIDs _does not mean_ multiple IP networks. (Only the opposite is true.) I really would be surprised if a router deliberately separated 2.4 GHz clients from 5 GHz clients purely because the networks had different names...

Comment: It has been a while since I had a non-google router. But the last time I did have one; it was separate. 2.4 devices couldn't see 5 and visa versa. But you bring up a great point - perhaps this isn't the case today or maybe even back then we had something setup wrong.

Comment: Asking for hardware recommendations is off-topic. Please [edit] and remove that part of your question.